# Android Animation of TextViews

Tags: android, layout, animation, android-layout

I basically have 5 text views that fill in one on top of the other. Rather then just all showing up like they do now, I want them to all come in with some animation, one after the other. Anyone have a link to a tutorial on how to animate TextView objects? only one I saw in the android docs involved using images as well as needing an image in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Animating a `TextView` is basically like [animating any other view](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View). If you want it to show up one after one, you can implement an [`AnimationListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/Animation.AnimationListener.html) and start the corresponding `TextView` when the previous has finished.